# unable to load Jqgrid onCellSelect

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I have one JqGrid which loads data from controller on Search button click. Code for button click event can be checked [here](https://github.com/saqib4342/new/issues/1).

```
public JsonResult GetAllMessages(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows, string messageType = "")
{
        int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
        int pageSize = rows;
        List<AllDBMessages> messages = _domain.GetMessages(messageType);
        var ListResults = messages.ToList().Select(
                a => new
                {
                    a.SerialNo,
                    a.MessageType,
                    a.TotalMessages,
                    a.Description,
                    a.Version,
                    a.MessageControlID,
                    a.SendingApplication,
                    a.SendingFacility,
                    a.ReceivingApplication,
                    a.ReceivingFacility,
                    a.DateTimeOfMessage,
                    a.DateInserted
                });

        int totalRecords = ListResults.Count();
        var totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)rows);
        if (sord.ToUpper() == "DESC")
        {
            ListResults = ListResults.OrderByDescending(s => s.MessageType);
            ListResults = ListResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        else
        {
            ListResults = ListResults.OrderBy(s => s.MessageType);
            ListResults = ListResults.Skip(pageIndex * pageSize).Take(pageSize);
        }
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = totalPages,
            page,
            records = totalRecords,
            rows = ListResults
        };
        return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

On first grid I have written **onCellSelect** event for Jqgrid which is fired for the first time but not second time. Controller code for fetching data for 2nd Grid is;

```
public JsonResult GetMessagesDetail(string messageType, string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
{
        return GetAllMessages(sidx, sord, page, rows, messageType);
}
```

Why my data is not loading **onCellSelect** second time. I have seen in DevTools that event is fired everytime but Jqgrid is not refreshed and action method is not fired second time.

Comment: How many **total** number of rows could be in the grid? (100, 1000, 10000, 1000000, ...) Which **version** of jqGrid you use (can use) and from which **fork** of jqGrid ([free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid), commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334) or an old jqGrid in version <=4.7). You displays grids with small number of columns (5-8) and small number of rows per page (`rowNum: 10`). Thus `loadonce: true` scenario (client side sorting, paging and searching/filtering) will work quickly with relatively large number of total rows (total messages).

Comment: Additionally I'm not sure that I correctly understand the problem with `onCellSelect`. Do you want to **reload** the 2-nd grid (detail grid) every time after the user select the row on the 1-st grid (master grid)? In the case you could create the second grid *only once* and then just trigger `reloadGrid` of `"#grid-table1"` inside of `onCellSelect` or `onSelectRow` callback of the 1-st grid: `$("#grid-table1").trigger("reloadGrid");`

Comment: Currently when my data is loaded in the grid first-time on cellClick. Second time it is loaded but, in order to see the updated data I have to manually press **Refresh**  button on second-grid and it is loaded fine. Why not on cell click of first grid. And, no not the detail grid it is another grid with new table id.

Comment: I tried to explain you in my previous comment, that your current code is wrong. You **creates** the second grid inside of `ShowMessageDetail`, but one can create it *only once*. After creating the initial empty table will be converted in relatively large number of tables and divs (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div)). Thus you have to use `$("#grid-table1").trigger("reloadGrid");` instead of call of `ShowMessageDetail` if the 2-d grid already created.

Comment: Thanks for sorting it out. But I think code is not wrong as I have fixed this by introducing new button and click and it loads fine. I think that OncellClick is not refreshing this by the way i did this to get refreshed data `$('#grid-table1').trigger("reloadGrid", [{
            page: 1
        }]);`

Comment: You are welcome! I repeat that the code of jqGrid tests whether the grid is already created or not. Only if the grid isn't created it creates it. If the grid already exist the second call of `.jqGrid({...})` will be just **ignored**. Thus you have two options: 1) recreate 2-nd grid always: call `GridUnload` before `.jqGrid({...})`. It's good way if you need to change the number of columns for example 2) reload **the data** in the second grid by calling `$('#grid-table1').trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @Oleg. I have fixed this with the help of this piece of code. Hope this help others too.

```
$('#grid-table1').trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The current code of `onCellSelect` is the following:

```
onCellSelect: function (rowId, iCol, content, event) {
    if (iCol == 1) {
        var type = $(grid_selector).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'MessageType');
        var version = $(grid_selector).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Version');
        ShowMessageDetail(type, version);
    }
}
```

where `ShowMessageDetail` **creates** the grid

```
function ShowMessageDetail(type, version) {

    var grid_selector = "#grid-table1";
    var pager_selector = "#grid-pager1";

    $(grid_selector).jqGrid({
        url: "/Home/GetMessagesDetail",
        datatype: 'json',
        postData: {
            messageType: function () {
                var messageType = type;
                return messageType === "" ? null : messageType;
            }
        },
        ...
    };
    ...
}
```

After the first call of `ShowMessageDetail` the empty table `<table id="grid-table1"></table>` will be converted in relatively complex structure of divs and tables (see [here](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#grid-internal-div)). The second call of `ShowMessageDetail` will just ignore creating the grid.

You can fix your code by usage either `ShowMessageDetail` or triggering `reloadGrid`:

```
onCellSelect: function (rowId, iCol, content, event) {
    if (iCol == 1) {
        var type = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'MessageType');
        var version = $(this).jqGrid('getCell', rowId, 'Version');
        var detailGrid = $("#grid-table1");

        if (detailGrid.length > 0 && detailGrid[0].grid) {
            // grid already exist
            detailGrid.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: 1 }]);
        } else {
            ShowMessageDetail(type, version);
        }
    }
}
```